# Bulk insert / Insert many with Play Framework, ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am building an app using Play Framework 2.5.0 and ReactiveMongo and I am spending a lot of time, stuck, on something that would be very easy to do in most web languages.

That thing is inserting many documents at once.
To do so, I must use the ReactiveMongo function `bulkInsert`.

I found [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/reactivemongo/rd4N16ziAD8/uZc75RCLWo0J) that had a very simple example, however it is from 2013 and now the signature changed

from

```
def bulkInsert[T](enumerator: Enumerator[T])
```

to

```
def bulkInsert(documents: Stream[P.Document], ordered: Boolean, writeConcern: WriteConcern)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[MultiBulkWriteResult]
```

So here I tried to take that example and find a way to convert Enumerator to a Stream (did not find any way to do so) :

```
val schemasDocs: Seq[JsObject] = {
  jsonSchemas.fields.map {
    case (field, value) => Json.obj(field -> value)
  }
}
val enumerator = Enumerator.enumerate(schemasDocs)
val schemasStream = Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(enumerator)) // my attempt to turn enumerator into a Stream
val schemasInsert = {
  getCollection("schemas").flatMap(
    _.bulkInsert(schemasStream, true)
  )
}
```

Now I find myself diving in the Akka, ReactiveMongo and Play API to try and create a Stream of JsObjects from a Seq of JsObjects..

Then I tried a different approach: the [example](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html#insert-multiple-document) from the ReactiveMongo's website

```
val bulkDocs = schemasDocs.map(implicitly[collection.ImplicitlyDocumentProducer](_))
collection.bulkInsert(ordered=true)(bulkDocs: _*)
```

gives me an error that is as hard to debug :

```
type mismatch; found : Seq[reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection#ImplicitlyDocumentProducer] required: Seq[x$48.ImplicitlyDocumentProducer]
```

I would rather not use Streams and use the second solution, as I don't like to have things I don't understand in my code..

Comment: Please have a look at the [examples](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.11.x/driver/src/test/scala/BSONCollectionSpec.scala#L72).

Comment: I still get that same error : type mismatch; found : Seq[reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection#ImplicitlyDocumentProducer] required: Seq[x$12.ImplicitlyDocumentProducer], I really don't get it

Comment: Your code is not sufficiently complete to understand it

Comment: I had also the  "type mismatch" issue with the ImplicitlyDocumentProducer,
I fixed this by adding the corresponding object with the implicit Json formatter.
`object Person {`
  `implicit val formatter = Json.format[FuelStation]`
`}`

Comment: for json `implicit val formatter = Json.format[FuelStation]` or for bson : `implicit val writer = Macros.writer[Person]`

Answer (score 2):

I just found how to handle bulkInsert. There is an example

**build.sbt**

```
...
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.14"
)
...
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.12")
```

**CxTransactionsRepository.scala**

```
package cx.repository

import cx.model.CxTransactionEntity
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class CxTransactionsRepository @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext){

  private val cxTransactionsCollectionFuture: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("cxTransactions"))

  def bulkInsert(seq: Seq[CxTransactionEntity]): Future[Int] = {
    for {
      transactions <- cxTransactionsCollectionFuture
      writeResult <- transactions.bulkInsert(ordered = false)(seq.map(implicitly[transactions.ImplicitlyDocumentProducer](_)): _*)
    } yield {
      writeResult.n
    }
  }

}
```